# Estender classes com construtor privado

Tags: java, android, orientação-a-objetos

Porque não posso estender classes com construtor privado?

Consirando as classes **A:**

```
public class A {
    private A(){}
    public static void limao(){}
}
```

e **B:**

```
public class B extends A {
    private B(){}
    public static void banana(){}
}
```

Por que **B** não pode estender **A**?

*There is no default constructor available my.package.name.A*

Meu objetivo é ter algumas classes que contém apenas membros estáticos e gostaria de garantir que elas sejam utilizadas da maneira correta (sem instâncias) mas que também herdam de outras classes por terem métodos em comum. Atualmente faço isso em C# atráves de classes estáticas mas não consigo aplicar algo parecido no meu projeto Android.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Se todos os métodos são estáticos, para que herdar da classe? Você pode simplesmente, na classe `B`, importar todos os métodos de `A` de modo que você continue podendo chamá-los sem precisar ficar usando `A.metodo`.

B.java

```
import static meu.pacote.A.*;

public class B {
    private B(){}
    public static void banana(){
        limao();
    }
}
```

Se for mesmo necessário herdar, use um construtor `protected` como sugerido por @Cigano Morrison Mendez. Ou, se as classes estiverem no mesmo pacote, um "package protected" (i.e. sem modificador) - pois isso evita que qualquer classe fora do pacote herde de `A`. Você pode ainda marcá-la como `abstract` (impedindo a instanciação) ou talvez lançar uma exceção no construtor (impedindo a instanciação de subclasses), se achar necessário tornar seu código "à prova de idiotas". Fica a seu critério...

Answer (score 8):

Porque isto vai contra a definição formal de proteção de métodos da teoria de orientação a objetos clássica. Se um membro é `private`, ele não pode ser acessado por nenhuma outra classe que não a própria classe.

Para este caso, use `protected` para que o construtor possa ser acessível pelas classes que extendem sua classe A.

Comment: Até onde eu sei o proteced é modificador de acesso que deixa visível a classe e/ou atributo para todas as outras classes e subclasses QUE PERTENCE AO MESMO PACOTE. Edit: Fonte http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: Neste caso não vale a pena eu mudar a resposta, porque a questão do pacote é própria do Java, e expliquei falando da teoria geral da orientação a objetos.

Answer (score 1):

Porque o construtor foi declarado como privado em A e o B não consegue acessar membros privados, apenas public ou protected. Quando você declara um construtor como privado nenhum outra classe vai enxerga-lo sendo impossível herdar da mesma ou instancia-la em outra classe.